# Views, Display Suite - fatal error on allowed memory size - what could be happening?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, display-suite

I am setting up my guitar lessons site which has categories via taxonomy and then lesson and exercise content types. Exercises are in a lesson, via entity reference. I am using Views and Display Suite. When I try to add a taxonomy view so I can list the lessons (along with the exercises therein), I get this:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in /home/user/dev.example.com/sites/all/modules/views/includes/base.inc on line 93

Here is what I did:

I created a view (content pane) for taxonomy terms of type lesson category. The goal is to have a display such as

```
Lesson 1
Lesson 1 Description
    Exercise 1 in Lesson
    Exercise 1 Description
Lesson 2
...
```

The view filters on taxonomy vocab (term Lessons), there is contextual filter on taxonomy id, and relationship Taxonomy term: Content using Category. I posted screen shot. [image]

I chose view mode lessons_in_category.

Then I wasn't sure what to do in Display Suite. I went to taxonomy (Lesson) content manage display, and for the lessons_in_category view mode I put the lessons in category view in the content. Screen shot attached.[image]

I keep getting the memory error. And seems to me it shouldn't actually be a memory problem. For instance, when I click on a category, it is not like that one category has so much content to generate a memory error. So I have a feeling there is some sort of infinite loop being generated somehow between views and display suite.

Ideas?

Comment: Stack traces are the biggest help here really. You need to enable full error output on your php.ini and that should hopefully output some useful info about the errors. I had a similar issue before when the views wasn't receiving an argument from panels, and that caused the site to stall until PHP ran out of memory or max execution time was exhausted.

Comment: In my experience 90MB is not enough. Official docs say [Typically 128 MB or 256 MB are found in production systems.](https://www.drupal.org/requirements/php#memory) so please reconsider your limits. Maybe there is nothing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP memory limit is being exceeded. In your drupal site, go to /admin/reports/status/php and look for "Loaded Configuration File". It should be one of the first 5 columns in the table.  In a plain text editor, or a code editor, open the file listed there. In it, search for `memory_limit` and replace the value next to it with, say, `128M'. Save that file and restart your web server. You may need to increase the memory limit again, if your server still errors out.

Comment: I thought about that, but I have a feeling the error is being triggered by an underlying issue, since even a category with one lesson and a few exercises generates the error. I might just be implementing views wrong in DS.  Do you know where in the code I would look to trace what is going on?

Comment: I never run Drupal on less than 128M. Try increasing that.

Comment: I increased to 256M but now I get Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: have you looked at the logs?

Comment: I just switched from Display Suite as the content type in Views to fields, and it works, albeit I really need to get DS working right so I can control the display fully. Will look at logs.

Comment: The error is Notice: Undefined index: load_comments in views_plugin_ds_entity_view->options_submit() (line 309 of /home/user/site.com/sites/all/modules/ds/views/views_plugin_ds_entity_view.inc) I had comment module disabled, thought maybe enabling would fix things, but no. Guess I'll have to troubleshoot this deeper.